# How do you access the Kubernetes dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes

Following the docs here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/

I've run `kubectl proxy` but as per the docs: "The UI can only be accessed from the machine where the command is executed."

Kubernetes is running on several servers on my network, and I would like to access the dashboard from my workstation.

First off: I'm confused as to what use case these docs cover? Are they expecting someone to have a KVM on their physical server and install xorg and a browser?

I can think of several other methods I could use here:

- Tunneling http traffic over ssh is certainly possible.
- VNC.
- X11 forwarding using SSH.

But each of these four methods is clearly a wrong / hacky approach.

How do you configure Kubernetes to allow traffic from say, a single IP address, to the dashboard?

Comment: Why not to use [recommended approach](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard#access)? Practically speaking what is already presented in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Run `kubectl proxy` on your workstation, not on the server, open `http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/.` in your local browser.

Comment: Interesting...so my workstation must be capable of running `kubectl`?

Comment: see https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/

Comment: @catpants Please consider [accepting the answer](https://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) if it solves your issue.